# Unable to access Geo Location in Webview android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am working on an android app based on a web view where I want to access the geolocation but can't I access it. I followed this tutorial [Enable Geolocation in a WebView (Android)](https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/how-to-enable-geolocation-in-a-webview-android/). everything is working fine but the only problem is that can't access geolocation.

Here is code of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webview"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

and MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.webview;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 
/**
 * A minimal WebView app with HTML5 geolocation capability
 *
 * @author David M. Chandler
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
    /**
     * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
     */
    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
     * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
     */
    public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
            // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }
 
    WebView mWebView;
 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acitivity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
        // Below required for geolocation
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
        // Load google.com
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Pop the browser back stack or exit the activity
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

I used **SDK API 19: android 4.4 kitkat**

tested on Marshmallow and Nougat.